# Present Continuous with "always"

Tags: present-continuous

- "We have been practicing twice a week since  the beginning of this
  season and that has really made a difference.  Now, some of the guys
  say that’s not necessary because we **always win**. "

Can I use here Present Continuous?: *"...because we **are always winning**."*  (as I know, I can use it with **"always"** not only for constantly happening **irritating** actions, but also for something **unexpected**, which happens several times. Am I right?)

Comment: please give an example, how you want to use present continuous

Comment: "because we are always winning."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, "we are always winning" is not the best choice. Exactly as you say, it would express the idea that winning would be an irritation, something undesirable. Maybe there is some irritation about *practicing*, but to express that, another sentence has to be built.

Therefore, "we always win" is the right form.

Regarding "unexpected" you are right only if it generates a negative feeling. It would be unnatural to say:

> I am always finding money in my pockets!

In this case, finding the money is **unexpected** (repeatedly), but with a conflict:

- irritation (I am always finding)
- joy, satisfaction (money in the pockets).

Of course, I assume that actually everybody will be happy to find money in the pockets (or anywhere else for that matter).